# Extract files that exist in folders from Zip Archive

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unzip

How can i extract files from directory that exist in Zip Archive,i uploaded zip archive from form(written in HTML),now if the Zip Archive contains folders i can't extract the files in side this folder,this is a snippet from my code:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
file_upload = form['file']
zfile=zipfile.ZipFile(file_upload.file,"r")
files_zip=zfile.namelist()
for name in files_zip:
  print name
  if name.endswith('/'):
      print "yes"
      l=list()
      l=os.listdir(name)
      print l
```

EDIT:
I tried to use `StringIO()` as:

```
s=StringIO(file_upload)
f=s.getvalue()
with zipfile.ZipFile(f,'r')as z:
         for d in z.namelist():
               print "%s: %s"%(d, z.read(d))
```

but the problem of the second snippet of code is:

```
No such file or directory: "FieldStorage('file', 'test.zip')
```

,i want to extract thse files to add them to GAE BlobStore??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's a working example of how to do this in [appengine-mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/).

Look at [input_readers.py](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/input_readers.py) for `BlobstoreZipInputReader` (which starts at line 898 at the moment).

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you are using `os.listdir` to list files inside zip data, you should just go thru names and extract data, here is a example where I create a in-memory zip file and extract files, even in a folder e.g.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from StringIO import StringIO

# first lets create a zip file with folders to simulate data coming from user
f = StringIO()
with ZipFile(f, 'w') as z:
    z.writestr('1.txt', "data of file 1")
    z.writestr('folder1/2.txt', "data of file 2")

zipdata = f.getvalue()

# try to read zipped data containing folders
f = StringIO(zipdata)
with ZipFile(f, 'r') as z:
    for name in z.namelist():
        print "%s: %s"%(name, z.read(name))
```

output:

```
1.txt: data of file 1
folder1/2.txt: data of file 2
```

As appengine doesn't allow writing to file system you will need to read file data (explained aboce) and dump it to blobs, you can just have a simple structure of name and data, but in you local OS you can try `z.extractall()` and it will create whole folder structure and files.

Comment: :in my question the user upload zip archive file from form,i need to read it,i used yor method in reading but this read files inside ZIP not folders?

Comment: @Eng_Engineer, in your case user is also uploading zip file data, not actual folder, so in my example first I created such data (which contain folder structure) I think it should work

Comment: @ Anurag Uniyal:i tried that ,i will edit my question,but the problem is still

Comment: @Eng_Engineer you don't need to wrap file_upload in StringIO, I have given you just an example to how to read some zipped data, in your case I think `zipfile.ZipFile(file_upload.file,"r")` should work, isn't it working?

Comment: i tried that,it isn't working also,this problem shown: **No such file or directory: '<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x04D33320>'**

Comment: :in addition to that i need the files inside the folder not the folder itself,because i want to store these files in BlobStore in GAE(doesn't support directories creation)